# how to query for distinct date result in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

**This is my document schema.**

```
   const smartpeepeeSchema = new Schema({
        owner: {
            type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true,
            ref: 'User',
        },
        baby: {
            type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true,
            ref: 'Baby'
        },
        data: [
            {
                _id: {
                    autoIndex: false
                },
                serialNumber: {
                    type: String,
                },
                macAddress: {
                    type: String,
                },
                firmware: {
                    type: String,
                },
                createdAt: {
                    type: Date,
                },
                humidity: {
                    type: Number,
                },
                temperature:{
                  type:Number
                },
                type:{
                    type:String
                }
            }
        ]
    });
```

and these are stored date as createdAt in my mongodb.

```
{ _id: 5c73e430ab6f3242b5c141c3,
  owner: 5c73c2e039ecd63e0edfebf1,
  baby: 5c73c2ea39ecd63e0edfebf2,
  data:[ 
      {createdAt: 2019-02-25T12:48:48.499Z,
       temperature: 23.2891,
       humidity: 1.82187,
       serialNumber: '01202117082100191',
       macAddress: 'D2:6A:95:5E:48:6E',
       firmware: '233',
       type: 'diaper' },
     { createdAt: 2019-02-25T12:48:48.499Z,
       temperature: 62.2587,
       humidity: 19.0473,
       serialNumber: '01202117082100191',
       macAddress: 'D2:6A:95:5E:48:6E',
       firmware: '233',
       type: 'diaper' },
     { createdAt: 2019-02-25T12:48:48.499Z,
       temperature: 19.8427,
       humidity: 68.2203,
       serialNumber: '01202117082100191',
       macAddress: 'D2:6A:95:5E:48:6E',
       firmware: '233',
       type: 'diaper' },
     { createdAt: 2019-02-25T12:48:48.499Z,
       temperature: 55.5166,
       humidity: 14.4124,
       serialNumber: '01202117082100191',
       macAddress: 'D2:6A:95:5E:48:6E',
       firmware: '233',
       type: 'diaper' } 
],
  __v: 0 }
```

**I want the result like this ?**

```
 {createdAt: specific date,
           temperature: 23.2891,
           humidity: 1.82187,
           serialNumber: '01202117082100191',
           macAddress: 'D2:6A:95:5E:48:6E',
           firmware: '233',
           type: 'diaper' },
         { createdAt: specific date,
           temperature: 62.2587,
           humidity: 19.0473,
           serialNumber: '01202117082100191',
           macAddress: 'D2:6A:95:5E:48:6E',
           firmware: '233',
           type: 'diaper' },
         { createdAt: specific date,
           temperature: 19.8427,
           humidity: 68.2203,
           serialNumber: '01202117082100191',
           macAddress: 'D2:6A:95:5E:48:6E',
           firmware: '233',
           type: 'diaper' },
```

**> I want to retrieve data for a specific date.

> if the client send to backend a data like '2019-02-24.
>
> The client must fetch all data for that date
>
> What should I do?..
>
> thank you for reading above all.
>
> from foreign developer.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `$gte` and `$lte` in your query, by adding time portion on your date. So the following range will represent the day:

```
00:00:00:000 -- 23:59:59.999
```

In your case if the input date is `2019-02-24`:

```
db.collection.find({"DateField" : {$gte : ISODate("2019-02-24T00:00:00.000Z"), "$lte" : ISODate("2019-02-24T23:59:59.999Z")}})
```

This query will return all the document which have a `DateField` for `2019-02-24`.

**EDIT**

In order to achieve what you want, you can run `aggregate`:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
[
    {$unwind : "$data"}, // This will open up your array
    {$match : {"data.createdAt" : {$gte : ISODate("2019-02-24T00:00:00.000Z"), "$lte" : ISODate("2019-02-24T23:59:59.999Z")}}} // This will filter to get only the date you need
]);
```

This will return only the object from the array, when `createdAt : 2019-02-24`:

Comment: Arsen Davtyan //it returns every obeject. I need specific date in array. .

Comment: Please update the question with the dateField you're trying to use and sample document which you're expecting your query to return.

Comment: Arsen Davtyan // this.is my query code with mongoose
  Smartbottle.find({
                owner: clientIdx,
                baby: babyIdx,
                'data.createdAt':{
                    $lte:'2019-02-25T12:49:01.000',
                    $gte:'2019-02-24T12:48:48.499Z'
                }
            })

Comment: but it returns like this 
{ _id: 5c73c5e784924a3e4ca24e42,
    owner: 5c73c2e039ecd63e0edfebf1,
    baby: 5c73c2ea39ecd63e0edfebf2,
    data: 
     [ [Object]],
    __v: 0 } ]